# Android 5.0 Admin Policy startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, device-policy-manager

I have an app with AdminPolicy since Android 4.0 and worked like a charm.

Now with Android 5.0 when i start the Admin check Activity, the app don't open the Activity, but flashes white and black.

This is my code that worked in Android 4.0 ...

```
private void checkAdmin() {
    if(!mDPM.isAdminActive(mPolicyAdmin)){
        Intent activateAdminIntent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);

        activateAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mPolicyAdmin);
        activateAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Policy Admin");

        startActivityForResult(activateAdminIntent, REQ_ACTIVATE_ADMIN_DEVICE);
    }else{

    }
}
```

Everytime I run this code, isAdminActive return always false, because startActivityForResult doesn't start nothing...

Why?

Comment: Did you use full path names in manifest file?
<activity android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity" ...>
<receiver android:name="com.example.app.AdminReciever" ...>

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution.

Leave in the Activity Manifest this line:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```